# How to make browsers trust a local network wss:// connection?

Tags: ssl, https, websocket

I'm trying to upgrade a websocket connection ws:// to wss:// using a nginx reverse proxy https://github.com/nicokaiser/nginx-websocket-proxy/blob/master/simple-wss.conf

but I seem to be having trouble with the certificate part. My server is located on the same network as the client. So Ideally I would want my users to log in to "https://example.com" and then the client makes a connection to "wss://192.168.1.xxx:xxxx".

As of now the browsers are blocking it because of NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. I don't really know to produce a self signed certificate that the browsers will trust on the local network. Googling only gives me answers on how to do it if my server would be accessed using a domain name but I will always connect to a local network IP. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To anyone coming across this I managed to solve it using this post outlining the architecture https://support.plex.tv/articles/206225077-how-to-use-secure-server-connections/

What ended up happening was that we set up a url pointing to a server running nginx which parsed the subdomain and redirected the connection to that url. For example: wss://192-168-1-142.mydomain.com redirects to ws://192.168.1.142 which makes the browser trust the connection

Comment: I gave an 'answer' rather than a comment. Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Your post is a year old now and browsers have become stricter since then. Usually, a browser will produce 'mixed content' errors if you access HTTP content from a HTTPS page, and the only way to get round this is to change the site settings to allow insecure content, which is scary for users in the face of a big warning message.

If accessing an HTTPS web address redirects to an HTTP local IP address, won't the browser still complain about mixed content?

I have a similar situation to you. I am writing a Progressive Web Application (PWA) to control network music players on a home network. The players only support HTTP but a PWA requires HTTPS for services workers to work and to allow the app to be 'installed'.

My solution is to run a local server on the home network which can talk to the players over HTTP. Then I can access this server over HTTPS from my browser so that the browser itself is not making any HTTP calls.

This works fine if the server is on localhost because localhost is a special case where security rules are relaxed. But if the server is on another machine, how can I create an SSL certificate since (1) it seems that local IP addresses are not allowed in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) section of the certificate, and (2) I won't know in advance what the IP address of the server will be.

If your workaround works, then the local server can use HTTP instead so I won't need a certificate. The local server can register itself with a web server, and then the browser can connect over HTTPS to the web server, which would redirect to the IP address of the local server over HTTP.

But does this trick work?